# Xamarin.Android project hangs indefinitely when trying to deploy to an Intel HAXM Accelerated Emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, deployment

I've recently downloaded **Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition** With Xamarin (almost 21Gig), followed by latest Android SDK (another 50 gigs or so) and related tools, along with Intel HAXM tool.

All the above installations are fully succeeded and supported on my Win8, Core i5, 8GB Ram desktop development box.

The issue is The AVD launches and the build process goes on and on for like ages (I just wanted to check how soon the simple 'Hello World' app is deployed and I've waited for 2 hours).

I got no error warnings no sign-of freezing anything within VS or on OS, yet nothing seems to working. The simulator shows up however the sample application is not being deployed

Only thing I suspect for now is change of SDK location which I believe, I took care of that already.

Please advise, what could be the reason (check the screen shots for more info)

[image]

Though the reg-edit change is made according to this forum
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64088/android-emulator-opens-but-project-does-not-deploy-and-start

[image: Registry Editor]

My SDK Manager is also fully updated

[image]

The AVD in question

[image]

Comment: Does this behaviour happen every time you try build and run? I.e. if you cancel the build and then build and run again (this time the emulator is open), does it deploy and run fine?

Comment: What are you Android build settings? Fast deployment enabled? Shared Runtimes enabled?

Comment: Yes Plac3Hold3r, This behaviour is everytime, Fast deployment or Shared runtimes, I am not yet aware of this settings(new to Xamarin), can you please suggest if I have to tick them in AVD or somewhere else

Comment: You can enable/disables these settings in Visual Studio-> Project Properties -> [Android Options](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/#Fast_Assembly_Deployment). You can try enabling/disabling the setting, [Xamarin Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37435) suggests other might be having a similar issue

Comment: Oh, that properties are ON by default, changing this it has no made impact so far..

Comment: Please add `adb logcat` logs and also `Diagnostic Build Output`. We need to distinguish the difference between `Build` and `Deploy` hanging. In your case, it is most likely that a `Deploy` is hanging, yet the project builds(I would edit your question title here). Some things to ensure on your end: 1) Make sure your SDK, JDK, NDK are all on the same hard drive. 2) Make sure your emulator boots up by itself. You can use `adb devices` to ensure it's running. 3) Try a `File -> New Android Project`. Ensure the emulator from the `adb devices` command is the default when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

The following trick worked for me,

I was not noticing the release mode can have issue (even debug mode is poorly working though)

[image]

Thanks **Plac3Hold3r** for pointing me towards properties, I wouldn't have
noticed the other factors, other wise. Wish I could have marked you
for an partial answer. Anyway thanks for your time, really appreciate
it.

Comment: Interesting, glad you found a workaround, but I believe this setting is required for the [debugger to function correct](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/debugger-settings/). Does disabling this not prevent your debugger from working?

Comment: Yeah, I read about it, seems something is bothering though, so no option till I find some concrete solution.

Comment: This is not a workaround. You will have 0 debugging functionality with this disabled.